# How to delivery results from long-running async runnable to activity?

Tags: android

An activity launches a long-running async task that runs in a background thread. This background task should return a result to the activity when completed (for instance, to notify a user about an operation success or failure)

Result could arrive at any time. Problems are that:
- the original instance object of the activity could be destroyed (e.g. a screen was rotated)
- there is no ready activity (the old activity destroyed, the new one is not started yet)
- a user changed the visible activity (pressed a back button, or pressed a home button, etc)

Please advice a design pattern for such technical task.

Answer (score 1):

> Result could arrive at any time. Problems are that: - the original instance object of the activity could be destroyed (e.g. a screen was rotated)

You could implement a rotation-aware `AsyncTask`, as described by Mark Murphy ("CommonsWare") [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/10/asynctask-screen-rotation.html).

> there is no ready activity (the old activity destroyed, the new one is not started yet)

If you mean because of the transition between `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `onCreate()`, read the post above, he explains why this shouldn't be a problem.

> a user changed the visible activity (pressed a back button, or pressed a home button, etc)

Otherwise, if you mean different `Activities`, long term data loading, I believe you could implement your own Loader (e.g., an `AsyncTaskLoader`) with satisfactory results, since they abstract all the usual life cycle overhead you would otherwise need to take care of.

Comment: I should also say that I've been following this simple method and I never had any problems regarding leaky results and tasks. This works.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to tackle this problem.

AsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncTask<Void, Void, T extends Parcelable> {
   private final Context mApplicationContext;

   public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
      mApplicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
   }

   public void onPostExecute(T result) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(String.format("%s.DONE", mApplicationContext.getPackageName()));
      intent.putExtra("Data", result);
      mApplicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
   }
}
```

And then in your activity:

```
public class FooActivity extends Activity {
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent data) {

           if (TextUtils.equals(data.getAction(), String.format("%s.DONE", context.getPackageName()) {
               Object o = data.getParacelableExtra("DONE");
               // DO SOMETHING WITH IT
           }
         }

     };

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
       ...
       registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(String.format("%s.DONE", getPackageName())));
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
       ...
       unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

}
```

OR

try this:

```
public class MYActivity extends Activity implements MyCustomAsyncTask.Listener {

    private MyCustomAsyncTask<?, ?, ?> mTask;

    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        if (mTask != null) {
            mTask.setListener(null);
        }
        return mTask;
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        mTask = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (mTask == null) {
            mTask = new MyCustomAsyncTask(....);
        }
        mTask.setListener(this);
    }
```

MyCustomAsyncTask

```
public class MyCustomAsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> extends AsyncTask {

      public interface Listener {
         public void doSomethingWithThis(Object o);
      }

      private mListener;

      public void setListener(Listener listener) {
           mListener = listener;
      }

      public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
          if (mListener != null) { 
             mListener.doSomethingWithThis(result);
          }
      }
...
}
```

Comment: I believe there are two issues: first, it's not clear (to me, at least) why you'd need a `BroadcastReceiver` to tackle this problem. Second, your edited example still does not show how you are going to let the finishing `Activity` be garbage collected on the orientation change. You must provide a way to (re-)attach and detach the listener in order to both not leak your Activity and get the result after the new Activity comes up. Your example will actually discard all the work if it's null. It won't be null (it will be a leaked one, exceptions will follow) and you aren't reusing the work done.

Comment: Hey look I think there are two issues with your comment. I never said it was needed, I said it could be done :) And the second issue looks like you didn't read the code. The first line of the onCreate will use the last known workable copy that was reattached to this activity.  If it doesn't exist then the last Activity didn't have one or it just wasn't possible to keep so we make a new one. And then reattach a listener. So if the instance is persisted, I trust the activity can manage it's own state for the results.

Comment: I added the cleaning of the listener in onDestroy to avoid the issues you speak of but my original intent was just to display the various ways you could do this. There is also the Loader way but it's actually a lot more verbose in my opinion

Comment: Yes, now that you are clearing the reference to the departing Activity, that stays inside the AsyncTask, it won't generate any leaks. That's what I meant. And by the way, you can remove the onDestroy code, since onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() happens exactly before that and after onStop(), thus being redundant. But yeah, now it works as far as I can tell.